# Generate this image with PHP

Tags: php, image

I want to generate this image in PHP with different colors for a skinning module in my app. How do I go about it?

image(2x40 pixels):

[image]

magnified 4x

[image]

The original image was generated using the gradient tool in paint.net with base color 00137F.

Comment: No chance of manually drawing the gradients in the 20 most popular hues? I guarantee you it's going to be easier than re-building the steps in PHP's GD library.

Comment: @Pekka Other gradients would do too.

Answer (score 2):

I've used this gradient class before, you may find it helpful:
http://planetozh.com/blog/my-projects/images-php-gd-gradient-fill/

Comment: Why do I get a This image cannot be displayed error in firefox when I am using $image = new gd_gradient_fill(200,200,'vertical','#fff','#fcc',0);